# Systemd bash builtins

Tags: bash, systemd, environment-variables, source

I have an application that needs to use the commando source for setting his environment file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Programname
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStartPre=source /opt/environmentname/bin/activate enviromentname
ExecStart=/var/programname/programname -f /etc/programname/programconfig.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, Systemd complains about source because this isn't an absolute path and source is a builtin of bash so I tried

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "source /opt/environmentname/bin/activate enviromentname"
```

That we run the script with source instead of chmod +x is because of vendor requirements.

So is there a way to get this working? Or do we need to work with forking or something?

How can we use bash builtins correctly inside Systemd unit files?

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to do a multi-line script eg

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '\
   source /opt/environmentname/bin/activate environmentname; \
   exec /var/programname/programname -f /etc/programname/programconfig.conf'
```

Answer (score 2):

To understand this... does `ExecStart` depend on the environment set by this command? Because these lines are actually not executed in the same shell, so you can't expect them to share the environment. What you need is to use the `Environment` keyword in the unit file. That way, the `ExecStart` will get the environment defined by your file.

https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html

Comment: Aha, yes, what happens in ExecStart is setting the environment but I've looked at Environment & EnvironmentFile and both require a non-executable command but just a list of environments.

Comment: A relevant thread for precisely your case:
https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2012-October/007273.html

But maybe you'd better just generate the environment, set it, and ten run your program in the same line (long bash line which runs more than one thing)

Comment: In other words: write a wrapper script.